# Javascript: How to intercept all prototype functions of a Class?

Tags: javascript, delegates, prototype, intercept

I need to know if a prototyped class understands a method. For example:

```
MyClass.prototype.myMethod1 = function() {
    ...
    return "Hello World!";
};

MyClass.prototype.myMethod2 = function() {
    ...
    return "Bye World!";
};

MyClass.prototype.caller = function(functionName){ //This is the method that I need to know
    if (functionName == "myMethod1") return "Exist!, is myMethod1.";
    if (functionName == "myMethod2") return "Exist!, is myMethod2.";
    return "Sorry, it doesn't exists here.";
}
```

This is just a poor example. I need to identify if the method is not understood for *MyClass* and, in that case, delegate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**This is not the actual answer to the question. The problem has been resolved in the comments. There is no actual answer to the question because Javascript does not have magic methods.**

So you need to check whether the object has a certain method? I think this is what you're looking for:

```
MyClass.prototype.caller = function(functionName) {
    // Check whether the property is a function
    if (typeof(this[functionName]) == "function") {
        // Method exists
        return true;
    } else {
        // Method does not exist
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, but _caller_ doesn't exist. I need to know how to modify _MyClass_ for checking when I do a wrong call. If I didn't _MyClass_ will execute that function, but if I did, _MyClass_ should alert me or delegate to another class.

Comment: @Lmyr You mean a function that will be called whenever you try to call a function that does not exist?

Comment: Yes! Like an Adapter. I need to get in between the function call and its execution.

Comment: @Lmyr this is afaik not possible.

Comment: Yes, @Lmyr, basilikum is right. There is no official way to do this. Mozilla Firefox has a `__noSuchMethod__` magic method, but it's not supported in any other browser. Also, it will most probably not become a standard.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to iterate over each method and property in the Prototype of MyClass using:

```
MyClass.prototype.hasMethod = function(name) {
  for (key in this) {
    if (key == name) 
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I need something like that but without redefining a "hasMethod" function. I need that _MyClass_ check it before trying to execute any function of it.